# How to display items on html table from django model base on its category

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have items in a Stock model and each item has a category that it belongs to. I want it to iterate through the Stock model, find the distinct category, display the items that relate to that category, and display the category name as a caption above the related items on the table.

model.py

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null = True)
    part_No = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    balance_bd = models.IntegerField(default='0', null = True)
    received = models.IntegerField(default='0', null = True)
    issued = models.IntegerField(default='0', null=True)
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,  decimal_places=2, null=True)
    obsolete = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)
```

views.py

```
def stock(request):
    stocks = Stock.objects.all()
    context = {
        'stocks':stocks,
    }
    return render(request, 'base/stock.html', context)
```

html template

```
 <!-- DATA TABLE-->
        <div class="table-responsive m-b-40">
            <table class="table table-borderless table-data3">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="bg-primary">
                        <th>NO</th>
                        <th>PART NO</th>
                        <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
                        <th>CATEGORY</th>
                        <th>UNIT</th>
                        <th>BALANCE B/D</th>
                        <th>RECEIVED</th>
                        <th>TOTAL BAL</th>
                        <th>ISSUED</th>
                        <th>TALLY CARD BAL</th>
                        <th>UNIT PRICE</th>
                        <th>TOTAL PRICE</th>
                        <th>ACTION</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    
                    {% for stock in stocks %}        
                    {% if stock.obsolete %}
                    
                    <tr>                        
                        <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
                        <td class="text-success"><i>{{stock.part_No}}</i></td>
                        <td class="text-success"><i>{{stock.item_name}}(obsolete)</i></td>
                        <td class="text-success"><i>{{stock.category}}</i></td>
                        <td class="text-success"><i>{{stock.unit}}</i></td>
                        <td class="text-success"><i>{{stock.balance_bd}}</i></td>
                        <td class="text-success"><i>{{stock.received}}</i></td>
                        <td class="text-success"><i>{{stock.total_bal}}</i></td>
                        <td class="text-success"><i>{{stock.issued}}</i></td>
                        <td class="text-success"><i>{{stock.tally_card_bal}}</i></td>
                        <td class="text-success"><i>{{stock.unit_price}}</i></td>
                        <td class="text-success"><i>&#162;{{stock.total_price}}</i></td>
                       
                        <td>
                            <div class="table-data-feature">
                                
                               <a href="{% url 'update-item' stock.id %}"> <button class="item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Update">
                                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-edit"></i>
                                </button></a>
                                <button class="item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete">
                                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-delete"></i>
                                </button>
                                
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
    
                    {% else %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
                        <td>{{stock.part_No}}</td>
                        <td>{{stock.item_name}}</td>
                        <td>{{stock.category}}</td>
                        <td>{{stock.unit}}</td>
                        <td>{{stock.balance_bd}}</td>
                        <td>{{stock.received}}</td>
                        <td>{{stock.total_bal}}</td>
                        <td>{{stock.issued}}</td>
                        <td>{{stock.tally_card_bal}}</td>
                        <td>&#162;{{stock.unit_price}}</td>
                        <td>&#162;{{stock.total_price}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="table-data-feature">
                                
                                <a href="{% url 'update-item' stock.id %}">  <button class="item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="update">
                                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-edit"></i>
                                </button></a>
                                <button class="item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete">
                                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-delete"></i>
                                </button>
                                
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    
                    {% endif %}

                {% empty %}
                <p>No item in stock</p>
                    {% endfor %}

                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td colspan="8" style="font-weight: bold;">TOTAL PRICE</td>
                        <td class="text-success" style="font-weight: bold;">&#162;{{sumTotalPrice}}</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div> 
        <!-- END DATA TABLE-->
```

These is the results I have so far
[my stock table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZWNB.jpg)

And I want it to look like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNNdD.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django Provided regoup template tag you can easily understand from Django official documentation

Link is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup)

Comment: Thank you very much @kadiwala. 
This link has solve my problem